# Oracle Apex Port Changing

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Apex version 4.2. It is configured to listen on port 8080 by default. How I am going to change the port of Oracle Apex after the installation?

Comment: This is possible but "how" is very dependent on your setup. Apex is just a database product which runs of a webserver. This could be the apex listener, the embedded plsql gateway or a http server of your choice. You'll need to clarify what it is you're running.

Comment: @Tom..yes it is apex listener which you are talking about...sorry 4 not mentioning that in Question...Kindly give me vote coz i am banned in stack-overflow for asking question... I will be thankful to you

Comment: @Tom..Kindly edit my question too so that it is clear to all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To find out which port Oracle Apex web app is configured on run:

```
select dbms_xdb.gethttpport from dual;
```

To change the port which Oracle Apex web app is configured on run:

```
exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport('8081');
commit;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to change the Port after initial installation and configuration of Oracle APEX. And infact you keep running APEX on more than one port at the same time (not advisable though .. only for testing/debugging).

Below code will set your new port to "7070" if you are using the embedded EPG for APEX.

> exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport('7070');

but you can change the port in HTTP server or RESTapi/Apex Listener config  as well and restart the Apex Listener or HTTP server which ever you are using, so that new port is active.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the installation guide, there is a command to change the port which you want [click here](http://www.snapdba.com/2013/04/installing-apex-4-2-and-configuring-embedded-plsql-gateway-epg/).

Answer (score 0):

You Can Change The Port By Running apex_conf.sql File. If You Run Apex Through a Web Server Then Change The Port Of The Web Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
SYSTEM_DRIVE:\ sqlplus /nolog
SQL> CONNECT SYS as SYSDBA
Enter password: sys_password
```

Enter the following statement to verify the port number:

```
SELECT DBMS_XDB.GETHTTPPORT FROM DUAL;
```

If the port number returns 0, the Oracle XML DB Protocol Server is disable.

For Enabling Oracle XML DB Protocol Server. Enter a statement similar to the following:

```
EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(port);
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out which port Oracle Apex web app is configured on run:

`select dbms_xdb.gethttpport from dual;`
To change the port which Oracle Apex web app is configured on run:

`exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport('8081');commit;`

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the apex listener port by executing this command from the database by connect with `sys user :EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(8089);`
Besides this you can change the port by running the `apex_conf.sql` file.